# 2 snmp packages; ports 161/162 already in use, can I configure additional ports?

Tags: networking

I have 2 snmp packages to install on a standalone server.  1 package is already using ports 161/162.  Where can I configure a Cacti Listener and which ports can I use?  Also which `snmpd.conf` file should I edit?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a `SNMP Port` option when creating a device on [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/graph_howto.html). As to which port you choose, well I get that depends on the [Management Interface Bases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol#Management_information_base_.28MIB.29) the two snmpd servers use and what you'd like to report on. You could take a look at what data is exposed with an `snmpwalk`. Assuming the server uses v1, then

```
snmpwalk -mALL -v1 -cpublic snmp_agent_Ip_address:port system
```

where `snmp_agent_Ip_address:port` are your system's IP and the 161 or 162 port. Or remove the system OID, and snmpwalk will default to `SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2` instead. You will probably have to change `-cpublic` to whatever your public read-only community string is, such as `-cmycommunity`.